# How to avoid interaction with "Build installdeps" in perl standard installation routine?

Tags: perl, build, automation, headless

A standard perl installation routine, e.g. for po4a 0.52 is

```
perl ./Build.PL PREFIX=/some/prefix
./Build installdeps
./Build
./Build install
```

how to avoid interaction with all of the commands, e.g.

```
Checking optional dependencies:
Install SGMLS? [y ]
```

during `./Build installdeps`.

I'm using this in a system bootstrapping script on an almost empty docker image in a headless environment (GitLab CI service), so solutions with a smaller list of dependent steps is preferred or those with longer ones.

I know about tools like `expect` (or `pexpect` in python), but they're complicated and require quite some amount of bootstrapping. I could research the sequence of input that makes sense and read it from a file, but I'd like to avoid that if there's an easier solution, like an argument I can pass to `Build`. I found http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1074554 which seems overly complicated.

Comment: Running `./Build installdeps` is an unusual way to install dependencies?! Why can't you install your distribution via the normal cpan/cpanm tools? You could then select whether you want to install suggested dependencies via command-line parameter.

Comment: There's an env var used by smokers. Don't remember what it is.

Comment: And of course, tying stdin to /dev/null might do the trick.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/11959600 help?